# Webapp not able to transmit special characters into SQL DataBase

Tags: python, html, sql-server, unicode

I have a web form where the analyst input their opinions. These opinions are then stored in a SQL database. The opinions are in free text format. when the analyst enter comments that contains parantheses (), doublt quotes "" or single quotes '' or apostrophes ' or em dashes.

I used the following code to ignore the error (I'm using Python for coding):

```
Comments = unicode(form.getvalue('Notes'), "utf-8", errors="ignore")
```

The code above removes the special characters and saves the updated comment.
I do not want that to happen. Is there a way to ensure that the special characters are not ignored and are added in the SQL database as is.

Comment: Yes. Use parameterized queries instead of building up strings and executing them.

Comment: If you get errors when decoding a byte string using UTF-8, then the data was encoded with a different encoding. What web framework are you using? It might provide a method which gives you decoded content already.

Comment: To be more precise: If en/em dashes or typographical quotes (“”, ‘’, «» etc.) ar missing, then this is most probably due to `errors="ignore"` removing them when decoding. If you have trouble with ASCII quotes or parentheses (the characters you listed), then the construction of the SQL `INSERT` statement is flawed, which is what @SeanLange's comment refers to.